# Pivot dataframe based on two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe consists of a .txt file with surveyquestions, and crossmarks indicating the answers. It looks like this and the goal is to transform this into a wide dataframe:

| Name | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | X |  |  |  |  |
| Ted |  | X |  |  |  |
| Chris |  | X |  |  |  |

I managed to stack the answers by this command:

```
s = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index()
```

which in turn gives the dataframe the following format:

| Name | level_1 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | X |
| Bob | B |  |
| Bob | C |  |
| Bob | D |  |
| Bob | E |  |
| Ted | A |  |
| Ted | B | X |

... and so forth

The end product ideally needs to look like this:

```
Name | Q1 
Bob    A    
Ted    B        
Chris  B
```

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: When I use `s = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index()` my output is already only the three lines you need.

Comment: @Paul the dataset was actually a text file, I think you destroyed what the real content is ;)

Comment: Then it is rather the import of the text file you need an answer to, right? How to get the text file to a proper dataframe?

Comment: Try something like `pd.read_table('PATH/TO/TXT_FILE.txt', sep='|')`

Comment: I guess this is the hardest part yes and it's not that simple. Or maybe this is simply bad formatting ?

Comment: Probably, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt`:

```
out = df.melt('Name', var_name='Q1').query("value == 'X'").drop(columns='value')
print(out)

# Output
    Name Q1
0    Bob  A
4    Ted  B
5  Chris  B
```

Answer (score 0):

If really this is not an issue of reading the file but only of reshaping, you could `stack`. This remove the NaNs by default without any selection:

```
(df.set_index('Name')
   .mask(lambda d: d.eq('X'))   # this is the important part to have NaNs
   .rename_axis('Q1', axis=1)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .drop(columns=0)
)
```

output:

```
    Name   Q1
0    Bob   A 
1    Ted   B 
2  Chris   B
```